# Dropdownlist first value display "choose"

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want that my dropdownlist display first value: "-choose car-"

I succeed at this way:

```
protected void ddl1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    Convert.ToInt32(ddl1.SelectedValue); 
    ddl1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-Choose car-", "-Choose car-"  )); 
}
```

and that's ok,the "-choose-" is in the first place but the problem now is that if I have values,for example,the dropdownlist show like that:

```
-Choose car-
Subaro
Fiat
Honda
```

The first value that display when I'm enter to the site is the Subaro,and  to see the -choose car- the user need to open the dropdownlist and then he will see the -choose car- at the first place.How can I do that from the start,from the page load - the -choose car- will display at the ddl from the page load.Where I wrong at the code ?

I tried the itemlist with `AppendDataBoundItems = "true"` but I got an error, and when I succeed,the problem is the same like I said before.

Comment: Did you try setting the `SelectedIndex` property to `0`?

Comment: If that dropdown list is bound, maybe the value is coming from database. Is it bound?

Comment: Did you do it in code **after** you added a new item at index 0, or did you just set it in the markup?

Comment: you have to set the selectedindex after adding the choose car listitem

Comment: first of all , thank you guys.
can you explain me more detailet what you mean ?

i made that:
         Convert.ToInt32(ddl1.SelectedValue);
         ddl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
         ddl1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-Choose car-", "-Choose car-"));

maybe i need to delete the values at the sql, then to add that code, and after that to add again values to the sql?

Comment: i'm adding items to the list through the table at the sql.. (the subaro, fiat, honda)

and then i put the code at the cs file, at the: protected void ddl1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e).. the code that i wrote at  my last comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were on the right track with using the [`AppendDataBoundItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems.aspx) property, it should be set to `true` if you're databinding the list.

Your markup should look like this

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl1" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="-Choose car-" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and your code behind probably already looks something like this

```
ddl1.DataSource = [your datasource goes here];
ddl1.DataBind();
```

This will place the **Choose car** text as the first option in the drop-down list and append the rest of the options below it.

---

Now for the more interesting part of **why** you were seeing the behavior you were seeing (first item not being selected).  If you look at the implementation of [`SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindex.aspx) using a tool like [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiling.aspx) (not affiliated with Telerik, just happen to use their tool) you'll see code that looks like this:

```
public int SelectedIndex
{
    get
    {
        int num = 0;
        num++;
        while (num < this.Items.Count)
        {
            if (this.Items[num].Selected)
            {
                return num;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    set
    {
        // stuff you don't care about

        this.ClearSelection();
        if (value >= 0)
        {
            this.Items[value].Selected = true;
        }

        // more stuff you don't care about
    }
}
```

As you can see, the index isn't stored anywhere, it's computed every time based on which item has the `Selected` property set to true.  When you set the `SelectedIndex` to 0 in the markup and databind your datasource, it will select the 0th item in that list, in your case `Subaro`.  When you insert a new item at the beginning of the list, `Subaro` is still marked as the selected item, which is why when the page loads, you see that selected and not `Choose car`.  If you want to mark `Choose car` as the selected item using code, you will have to do it after you data databind your dropdown.  **Please note, this is just an implementation detail of how `DropdownList` works.  It could change in future version of ASP.NET so do not write code that relies on it working this way.**

Comment: Thank you all.
at the end, the probleme was so stupied :)... i have 4 cascading ddl's... and all what i have to do was to add at the markup of any of them - AppendDataBoundItems="true" .. and set the value of the listitem to 0 !

the next step was to to if (!ispostback) { ddl2....clear (...)insert="-choose-"} at the selectedindexchanged .. from the reason that even after postback the user will see the choose.

all work fine now.

so the prob was that all the ddl's connected each other with WHERE.. and for avoid errors, each of them was need  AppendDataBoundItems="true" and value=0 at listitem.

Comment: @Bside: You probably should have mentioned they were cascading dropdowns in your question.  Not sure if my answer helps in your case.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure that you bind the data source and insert you "-choose care-" item first before selected he first item
2. make sure when you insert your 1st item "-Choose car-" you make it once not on each PostBack. Check if not `IsPostBack` to add the 1st item.
   EDIT:
   Example:

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      if(!IsPostBack)
      {
         ddl1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-Choose car-", "-Choose car-"  ));
      }

       ddl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You should do `ddl1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-Choose car-", "-Choose car-"));` first, and than `ddl1.SelectedIndex = 0`

Comment: ok, where i need to do that? at the ddl1_DataBound ?
or at the page_Load ?

Comment: Try on page load then. But like this: if(!IsPostBack){ --your code-- }

Comment: please don't suggest randomly moving code around until it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
        private void FillCar()
        {      
            DataTable dt = GetCar();
            ddl1.Items.Clear();
            ddl1.DataSource = dt;
            ddl1.DataTextField = "carName"; // field name in the database
            ddl1.DataValueField = "CarNum"; // field name in the database
            ddl1.DataBind();
            ListItem li = new ListItem();
            li.Text = "--Choose car--";
            li.Value = "-1";
            ddl1.Items.Insert(0, li);
            ddl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
```

I use method like this and call it in the page load in `if (!IsPostBack){}`.

Comment: you think that maybe the problome is that i used LINQ to SQL ?

how i'm connect the ddl for what you wrote here?

Comment: no , i don't know how you bind your drop down list, but i think this is a simple method to do what you want perfectly.

Comment: you can still use LINQ to SQL

Comment: what is the GetCar(); ... ? method?

Comment: this is a supposed method to `Select` the data from the database to fill the drop down list, u can use your method to set the datasource.