# change first item dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I got a Dropdownlist that is databind but I want to change the first value.
but this don't work

```
var Movies = Directory
                             .GetFiles(MapPath("~\\Movies\\" ), "*.mp4")
                             .Select(p => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p))
                             .ToArray();

                Dropdownlist1.DataSource = Movies;
                Dropdownlist1.DataBind();
                Dropdownlist1.Items[0].Value = "Choose one";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856359/dropdownlist-first-value-display-choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to insert new value at zero index of dropdown items, you need to use `Dropdownlist1.Items.Insert` to add element at the first location.

```
Dropdownlist1.DataSource = Movies;
Dropdownlist1.DataBind();
Dropdownlist1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Choose one", "Choose one"));
```

Comment: and how can I delete 1 item out the dropdownlist

Comment: @Will_G Dropdownlist1.Items.RemoveAt(0);

Comment: Thanks @GopeshSharma, you can also use .Remove

Answer (score 0):

Just set AppendDataBoundItems property to true on your dropdownlist. Then add a new list item in your aspx code like

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlInstallTypes" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="odsTreatyInstallTypes" DataTextField="DisplayText" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
            DataValueField="Value"> <asp:ListItem Text="- Select -" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

This way a new list item will be added to the list on top.